# In angular form span can not be displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am not able to see error message on clicking the submit button using angularjs.
Any lead will be appreciated
Thanks in advance :)

```
<form id="formbody" ng-submit="submituser(form)" name="form" novalidate>

    <input type="text" ng-class="{ errorinput: submitted && form.dob.$invalid }" name="dob" ng-model="dob" placeholder="Date of Birth" required />
    <span class="e" ng-show="submitted && form.dob.$invalid">Please provide a valid date of birth</span>

    <div style="padding-left: 275px;">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <!--  <div  type="button" id="btn" style="color: red;" >Submit</div> -->
    </div>
    </div>
</form>

.controller('ExampleController', function($scope, $location, $scope, $stateParams) {
    $scope.singleSelect = '';
    $scope.goToPage = function() {
        console.log("selectservice");
        $location.path("/selectservice");
    }
    $scope.submituser = function($scope) {
        if ($scope.form.$valid) {} else {
            $scope.submitted = true;
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try something like that**

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form" ng-app>
<div class="control-group" ng-class="{true: 'error'}[submitted && form.dob.$invalid]">
        <label class="control-label" for="dob">Your Date of Birth</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="dob" ng-model="dob" required />
            <span class="help-inline"  ng-show="submitted && form.dob.$invalid">Please provide a valid date of birth</span>
          
        </div>
    </div>
   
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" ng-click="submitted=true">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

please check the form name

you have used two different names

**name ="form"** in form tag  and used as **signUpForm.dob** in input field.

Check your **ng-model** to

```
<form id="formbody"  ng-submit="submituser(form)" name="signUpForm" novalidate>

 <input type="text" ng-class="{ errorinput: submitted && signUpForm.dob.$invalid }" name="dob" ng-model="form.dob" placeholder="Date of Birth" required />
    <span class="e" ng-if="submitted && signUpForm.dob.$invalid">Please provide a valid date of birth</span>

  <div style="padding-left: 275px;">
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</div>
    </form>


.controller('ExampleController',function($scope,$location,$scope, $stateParams){
     $scope.singleSelect='';

     $scope.goToPage=function(){
        console.log("selectservice");
        $location.path("/selectservice");
     }
     $scope.submitted =false;

     $scope.submituser = function(form){
      // console.log(form);
             if (form.$valid) {
           your logic 
    } else {
      $scope.submitted = true;
    }
  }

    })
```

Comment: I have corrected it and now error is coming.
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'signUpForm' of undefined
    at ChildScope.$scope.submituser"

Comment: $scope.submituser function name in controller and you are calling some signUpForm() in the template ng-submit="signUpForm()"

Comment: Yes previously i  have wriiten that but after correcting it this error is coming.

Comment: try the above one

Comment: Yes it's working but i want span to be appear after clicking on the submit button.

Comment: in controller make initial value as false, $scope.submitted =false; before the fun call, and use ng-if instead ng-show

Comment: Error is not coming but span is appearing on the refresh of page .

Answer (score 1):

change `ng-show` of `span` to

```
 <span class="e" ng-show="submitted && form.dob.$invalid">Please provide a valid date of birth</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the form name but even after that you cannot refer to your form in controller unless you pass it through the submit function arguments. Also there is not `signupForm()` function in your controller.

The way to go is :

```
<form id="formbody" name="myForm"  ng-submit="signupForm(myForm)" novalidate>
<!-- inputs etc -->
</form>
```

Then based on `submituser()`:

```
$scope.signupForm = function(myForm) {
        //Do whatever you want to do
        if(myForm.$valid) {
            //some logic
        }else {
            $scope.submitted = true;
        }
    }
```

On the other hand if you don't want to mess up with the controller you can always use `FormController` method `$submitted`. This would look like:

```
<span class="e" ng-show="myForm.$submitted && myForm.dob.$invalid">Please provide a valid date of birth</span>
```

Comment: there is no need to send form as a parameter.